# Django REST Framework serializer for a list of dictionaries

Tags: serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm new to Django REST Framework and searching for a method to serialize a list of dictionaries.

Target data is a time-series. Each dictionary contains hourly value and each list contains hourly values of a day.

```
class Hourly:
   hour = None
   value = None

   def __init__(self, hour, value):
      self.hour = hour
      self.value = value


class Daily:
   date = None
   vlist = None

   def __init__(self, date, vlist):
      self.date = date
      self.vlist = vlist
```

It is easy to create a serializer for the hourly class by following the [Django REST Framework API guide](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/).

```
class HourlySerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    hour = serializers.IntegerField(required=True, min_value=0, max_value=23)
    value = serializers.FloatField(required=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Hourly(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.hour = validated_data.get('hour', instance.hour)
        instance.value = validated_data.get('value', instance.value)
        return instance
```

My objective is simple: creating a serializer for the daily data.
(1) The serializer must restrict the length of data as 24. (2) It should have an ability to validate each hourly data.

#1. Using `ListField`

In case of restricting the data length, `ListField` has arguments `min_length` and `max_length` [#](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#listfield).

I think this kind of code may be possible [#](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/3274), however, the API guide does not say anything about defining the `child` of a `ListField` as a serializer.

```
class DailySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    date = serializers.DateField(required=True)
    vlist = serializers.ListField(child=HourlySerializer(), min_length=24, max_length=24)
```

#2. Using `ListSerializer`

The [API guide](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-nested-objects) says one can nest serializers just like they are fields. If the nested value is a list of items, `many=True` can be used to initiate `ListSerializer`. However, there is no argument about restricting the data length.

```
class DailySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    date = serializers.DateField(required=True)
    vlist = HourlySerializer(many=True)
```

Here are my questions:

1. Is the method using `ListField` is possible with no problem? Or, can I pass `min_length` and `max_length` arguments with `many=True`?
2. The API guide does not say anything about defining `create()` and `update()` for `ListField` or `ListSerializer`. There are only cases for a nested serializer without `many` option [#](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writing-create-methods-for-nested-representations) and a `ListSerializer` without non-list field [#](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#customizing-multiple-create). Is there any example about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer to my own question.

```
class DailySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
   date = serializers.DateField(required=True)
   vlist = serializers.ListField(child=HourlySerializer(), min_length=24, max_length=24)

   def create(self, validated_data):
      return Daily(**validated_data)

   def update(self, instance, validated_data):
      instance.date = validated_data.get('date', instance.date)
      instance.vlist = validated_data.get('vlist', instance.vlist)
      return instance
```

Above `ListField` based `DailySerializer` is tested with the below input.

```
[
{'date': '2000-01-01', 'vlist': [{'hour':'00', 'value': '012'}, {'hour':'01', 'value': '123'}, ...],
{'date': '2000-01-02', 'vlist': [{'hour':'00', 'value': '012'}, {'hour':'01', 'value': '123'}, ...],
...,
]
```

To deal with the additional multi-day nest, serializer in the view is defined with `many=True`.

```
serializer = DailySerializer(data=data, many=True)
```

Test results are below:

1. Using the `ListField` method does not make any problem during validation.
   Changing some hourly value as an arbitrary string is detected as an non-integer value.
   Daily data with its length not equal to 24 is also detected.
2. Using naive `create()` and `update()` methods with `ListField` can be problematic.

- `obj_list = serializer.validated_data` returns a List of OrderedDict objects.
- `obj_list = serializer.save()` returns a List of `Daily` objects.
  However, `obj_list[0].vlist` is a List of OrderedDict objects, not a List of `Hourly` objects.